# Feel like sticking to only one design pattern

Tags: design-patterns

I am new to design patterns. On trying to solve on problem with design patterns, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088711/game-of-life-with-facade-design-pattern) Facade method to be appropriate. And it worked well for me.

Now that I am trying to apply designs to other problems, I keep trying to apply the very same facade pattern! Is there anyone else who has experienced this?

And thumb rules while applying patterns?

Comment: The whole point of patterns is that there are different patterns for different problems. I would advise you to learn some other patterns rather than trying to use the same one all the time (unless of course you have a similar problem to solve that requires the facade pattern again)

Comment: @Mathematician: Is there any thumb rule you apply for determining the right design pattern?

Comment: Get familiar with the most used patterns (Factory, Repository, Facade, Adapter, Observer...), and you will recognize situations where they are fit immediatly.

Comment: @TheSilverBullet If you read about the most popular ones, you will start to get a feel for when they are useful for a given situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to purchase this great book: [Head First Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do). If you just look at the book's source code you'll also get some idea when and how to use what pattern for a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks, Lorand. I already have Gang of four book. And also am referring to [dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx). I am aware of design patterns, but my problem is preference to one that worked...

Comment: But the link you provided also gives you hint which one to use for a specific problem. E.g:
`,, ...different vehicles are assembled in a step-by-step fashion" (Builder)`. Since you can't solve `every problem` with the facade pattern, you should try out others if you want use patterns at all. Head First Design Patterns explains them in an `understandable` way.

Comment: @Leorand, I will try that book for sure!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I felt (and still feel) like using Facade pattern is because it is familiar and it "worked".

The approach I am currently taking is that, I will implement at least one problem for each pattern (right now I am at memento). While this will take long, I get the feeling that it gets easier - the more new patterns I try out.